# Merge developement branch with other branch in tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I am using tortoise SVN and I am working on a separate branch other than development branch. My work on that branch might last more than 2 weeks or so till than if development branch is updated my code will be outdated. 
I need to keep on updating my working branch from main development branch, I use merge with all revisions but it replaces my branch files with development files instead of showing me the conflicts and this means that my changes are lost which I made while working on my new branch.
I want tortoise SVN to show me conflicts with line numbers or at-least show me mine and theirs so I can resolve conflicts and keep my working branch up to date. Thanks in advance.

I am using tortoise for windows, tortoise SVN gui tool for windows 7. TortoiseSVN 1.8.2 I am right clicking on folder to merge and select repository url and select all revisions radio button for revisions.

Comment: You're probably performing the merge wrong. Post the svn command line you're using to do the merge.

Comment: I am using tortoise for windows, tortoise SVN gui tool for windows 7. TortoiseSVN 1.8.2